# How to hide the API Key using angularjs resource

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have build an Rest-API with SLIM (PHP Framework). Whats the best way to protect this API? I think about using a API-Key, but he will be visible in the JavaScript-code for everyone? Do you have any ideas for me?

Thank you!

Comment: You could implement asymmetric security with private/public keys; as long as the private key is protected on your server (behind a firewall etc...), then you can share the public key with trusted users...

Comment: authenticate over https then use a token to authorize api calls.This question has little to do with angular.

Comment: Thank you! hmm i dont want it to share with users. I only will make sure that the request come from my website. Is a CSRF-token a better choice than a API-Key for my problem? How can I send them in a secure way to angular with SLIM?